# Send delete key in Chrome Input.dispatchKeyEvent API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just want to send a delete key in the Chrome extensions API, but it doesn't work but doesn't do anything.

I tried:

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", { type: 'rawKeyDown', keyIdentifier: 'U+2421' })
```

And:

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", { type: 'rawKeyDown', keyIdentifier: 'Delete' })
```

But neither worked.

How can I type a "delete" in the API?

Comment: Also, I'd like to know if there is a list of available keyIdentifiers out there.

Comment: Try `code: 'Delete'`. You can use https://keycode.info or MDN for [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_code_values) and [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values) lists.

Comment: Solved by that. Thanks!