# Javascript how to simulate keystroke for {IsTruested:true}?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to automate in 3rd party site using chrome console. For that I required to enter strings in a input field(its actually a

para which is being used as input).

For that I am using the below to simulate keystroke.

```
Code:
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'a'}));
```

But got the below error.

```
Error:
[{"isTrusted":true}]
console.error @ ?agent=web&version=23010100913:98
handleError @ ?agent=web&version=23010100913:109
```

I also tried element.value += "a" but the value is not getting changed.

After searching on internet ([How to trigger an ‘isTrusted=true’ click event using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853588/how-to-trigger-an-istrusted-true-click-event-using-javascript)) I tried the below code.

```
chrome.debugger.attach(element, "1.2", function() {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(element, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", arguments)
})
```

But got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attach')".
I think I haven't given permission or something, I am unable to figure it out.

Edit:

manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "name" : "Teams",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

I am not a developer, hence do not have a good understanding to chrome.debugger.

Kindly help me to simulate keystroke.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is similar to this. [Send delete key in Chrome Input.dispatchKeyEvent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373336/send-delete-key-in-chrome-input-dispatchkeyevent-api)

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I tried it, but getting error "VM6592:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendCommand')". Code: "chrome.debugger.sendCommand(element, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", { type: 'rawKeyDown', code: 'KeyH' })".

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with manifest.json, please post it.
yeah? No way, it's not a chrome extension?

Comment: manifest.json "{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "name" : "Teams",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}" -- I wanted to directly paste javascript code in chrome console, I don't want to add that code in javascript file.

Comment: It's hard to read, so please add it to the question instead of commenting.

Comment: Your extension is missing the "debugger" permissions